# How integrate wordpress log-in + Register in an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ios4, buddypress

I would like to know of any way to let a user log in or register on the iPhone app and then he will be linked to the wordpress site.

Thanks
Please ask you want more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would start here: [WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s)